# Restore a single database backup (.bak) file into multiple filegroups

Tags: sql-server, ssms, backup, sql-server-2014, restore

I have a SQL Server 2014 database `DB01` (single filegroup - PRIMARY) and I took a backup of it into a `DB01.bak` file in SSMS.

I have another database `DB02` with 1 primary filegroup (1 file) and one secondary filegroup (2 files). I am trying to restore the `DB01.bak` file into DB02 with multiple filegroups. Is it possible to do this in SSMS?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to do what you are asking.  SQL is backing up the current state of the database.  What tables are in what filegroup is part of the database information. It is possible to restore the backup to a new database name.  Once the data is on the new server you could research and create the file groups you want, make your changes, etc.   Get everything you the way you want it.   Back it up a final time and then restore it to the database name you want or you can simply rename the database.  Depending on the size it might be faster to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to do like that.
 need to do data migration DB01 to DB02.